# How to add new functionalities to a class without change the called method in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns

I would like to design a class which can (or not) implement functionalities, and be open to add new ones in the future. Those functionalities must be executed by a method. For instance:

```
class Hero()

doDamage(){
//simpleDamage
}
```

And

```
class BetterHero() implements EnableCriticAttack

doDamage(){
//damage with critic attack chance
}
```

Also,

```
class WizardBetterHero() implements EnableCriticAttack, MagicDamage

doDamage(){
//damage with critic attack chance + magic damage
}
```

I would like to add new "special abilities" using the proper design pattern, so `doDamage()` method will know which abilities to use, and it does properly. I don't want to create different classes, just "add" new functionalities to the created one: open-close principle.

PD: I put the functionalities as interfaces, but it is just an example.

Comment: Adding new functionality doesn't violate O/C. How else are you supposed to scale up an existing type? O/C is violated when you make modifications to *existing* code, not when you add new functions that don't require modifying existing code. Classes are *open for extension* (add new functionality), but *closed for modification* (modifying existing code). "Extension" is not referring to using `extends`.

Comment: @VinceEmigh "Extension" is not referring to using extends. I know, I just asking this question here to know if there is a proper way to do what I am trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different ways of inflicting damage is a behavior which suggests using the Strategy design pattern.  For example, have a `Damage` interface such as:

```
public interface Damage {
    public void doDamage();
}
```

and a few implementations such as:

```
public class SimpleDamage implements Damage {
    public void doDamage() {
        System.out.println("simple damage");
    }
}

public class MagicDamage implements Damage {
    public void doDamage() {
        System.out.println("magic damage");
    }
}
```

So then there is only a need for a single `Hero` type such as:

```
public class Hero implements Damage {
    private final Damage damage;

    public Hero(Damage damage) {
        this.damage = damage;
    }

    public void doDamage() {
        damage.doDamage();
    }

}
```

Implementations of `Damage` could also use the Decorator design pattern.  For example, a Hero's damage could include mulitple ways to inflict damage:

```
public class MagicDamage implements Damage {
    private final Damage additionalDamage;

    public MagicDamage(Damage additionalDamage) {
        this.additionalDamage = additionalDamage;
    }

    public void doDamage() {
        if (additionalDamage != null) {
           additionalDamage.doDamage();
        }
        System.out.println("magic damage");
    }
}
```

...

```
Hero hero = new Hero(new MagicDamage(new SimpleDamage());
```

Comment: Hi, I like those ones. I am thinking about a private List<Damage> Hero attribute, and a addDamageSkill() method. Thanks!